# Localstack Service "s3" not yet available, retrying

Tags: amazon-s3, localstack

> Service "S3" not yet available, retrying.

I am using localstack docker image.

When I am hitting the command:

```
docker run -it -p 4567-4578:4567-4578 -p 8080:8080 localstack/localstack
```

I am getting errors: `S3 is not yet available`

I am using MacOS.

[image: S3 is not yet available]

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution.
Try to run the services that you need.

```sh
docker run -p 4569:4569 -p 4572:4572  -p 4575:4575 -p 4576:4576  -e SERVICES=dynamodb,s3,sns,sqs -p 8080:8080 localstack/localstack
```